# Which function has the following Taylor series?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I would like to know if the following Taylor series have a nice closed form:

$$f_k(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{(n+k)n!}\qquad k=1,2,3,\ldots $$
$f_1(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$, but what about $f_2,f_3,f_4,\ldots$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

From

$$x^ke^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{k+n}}{n!}$$ one deduces

$$\int_0^xx^ke^xdx=x^{k+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(n+k)n!}.$$

The antiderivative will be of the form $P(x)e^x$ where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $k$, such that $P(x)+P'(x)=x^k$.

For instance, with $k=5$,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(n+k)n!}=\frac{(x^5-5x^4+20x^3-60x^2+120x-120)e^x+120}{x^6}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! You just saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

> **Claim**: for any $k\in\mathbb{N}^+$, $$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{n}}{(n+k)n!} = \frac{p_k(x)e^x+(-1)^{k+1}k!}{x^{k+1}}\tag{1}$$ where
>   $p_k(x)$ is a polynomial with degree $k$.

The claim is trivial for $k=1$: $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$. In the general case, we may notice that
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left(x^{k+1}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{n}}{(n+k)n!}\right) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{n+k}}{n!}=x^k e^x\tag{2}$$
so by integrating both sides we get:
$$ p_k(x) = x^k-kx^{k-1}+k(k-1) x^{k-2}-k(k-1)(k-2) x^{k-3}+\ldots \tag{3}$$
or:
$$ p_k(x) = k!\sum_{j=0}^{k} x^{k-j}\frac{(-1)^j}{(k-j)!}.\tag{4} $$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\mrm{f}_{k}\pars{x}  \equiv
> \sum_{n \geq 0}{x^{n} \over \pars{n + k}n!}:\ {\large ?}
> \qquad k = 1,2,3,\ldots}$

\begin{align}
\mrm{f}_{k}\pars{x} & \equiv \sum_{n \geq 0}{x^{n} \over \pars{n + k}n!} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{x^{n} \over n!}\int_{0}^{1}y^{n + k - 1}\,\,\,\dd y =
\int_{0}^{1}y^{k - 1}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{xy}^{n} \over n!}\,\dd y =
\int_{0}^{1}y^{k - 1}\expo{xy}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{xy\ \mapsto\ y}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over x^{k}}\int_{0}^{x}y^{k - 1}\expo{y}\,\dd y =
\bbx{\ds{\left\{\begin{array}{lcrcl}
\ds{\Gamma\pars{k} - \Gamma\pars{k,-x} \over \pars{-x}^{k}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x} & \ds{\not=} & \ds{0}
\\[2mm]
\ds{1 \over k} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x} & \ds{=} & \ds{0}
\end{array}\right.}}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\Gamma\pars{k}}$ and $\ds{\Gamma\pars{k,-x}}$ are the
>   [$Gamma\ Function$ and the $Incomplete\ Gamma\ Function$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_255.htm), respectively.